# continuous maps basis to basis

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T_X)$, $(Y,T_Y)$ be topological spaces, $f \colon X \to Y$ $B_X, B_Y$ a subbasis on X resp. Y. To check if $f$ is continuous, it is sufficient that $f^{-1}(B_Y) \subset T_X$.

If we look on basis or more general a subbasis with the smallest cardinality, are there a class of continuous functions that satisfy $f^{-1}(B_Y) \subset B_X$?

**EDIT**, that were the old quests, that are redundant as every basis is also a subbasis:
2) Are there continuous functions satisfying the same even for $B_X,B_Y$ being basis with smallest cardinality $\omega(X,T_X)$, resp. $\omega(Y,T_Y)$ .
3) when is it sufficient just to check for a basis $B$ of Y that $f^{-1}(B) \subset T_X$.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, to check that $f$ is continuous you need to check $f^{-1}[B] \in \mathcal{T}_X$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}_Y$. This is necessary and sufficient.
A base instead of a subbase would do just as well.

$f^{-1}[\mathcal{B}_X]$ makes no sense: we can only take pre-images of subsets of $Y$ when $f:X \to Y$.

It could happen that $f^{-1}[\mathcal{B}_Y] \subseteq \mathcal{B}_X$, but it's not ensured to be the case. We could have a strictly increasing bijection between ordered spaces, say.

Comment: thanks i corrected that. Would also be a basis of the topology instead of a subbasis just ok? For your last point, would eg. the identity work? or could you give an example where basis is send to basis elements? I would be curious if there is a class of functions behaving so.

Answer (score 1):

For 1. let $(X,T_X)=(Y,T_Y)=(\Bbb N, D)$ where $D$ is the discrete topology. A base (basis) or sub-base for $D$ cannot be finite but it can be countable.

Let $B_X=\{\{n\}\}: n\in \Bbb N\}.$ Let $$B_Y=\{A(n):n\in \Bbb N\}\cup \{B(n): n\in \Bbb N\}$$ where $A(n)=\{n\}\cup \{n+2t: t\in \Bbb N\}$ and $B(n)=\{n\}\cup \{n+2t-1:t\in \Bbb N\}.$

Note that $B_X$ is a base, and a fortiori a sub-base for D.  And $B_Y$ is a sub-base for $D$ because $\{A(n)\cap B(n): n\in \Bbb N\}=\{\{n\}: n\in \Bbb N\}$ is a base for $D.$

Now $A(1) \cup B(1)=\Bbb N=Y$ so for any $f:X\to Y$ we have $$\Bbb N=X=f^{-1}Y=f^{-1}(\,A(1)\cup B(1)\,)=(f^{-1}A(1))\,\cup \,(f^{-1}B(1))$$ so it is not possible that both $f^{-1}A(1)$ and $f^{-1}B(1)$ belong to $B_X.$

Comment: oh you claim with this that it is also dependent on the topology and for the discrete topology it wont work with any map, great.

Comment: Can you explain in detail why the even and odd numbers both can not belong to the singleton n sets?

Comment: I don't understand that. BTW I thought of other examples.(1). Let $X=Y=\Bbb R$. Let $B_Y$ be the set of open half-lines. Let $B_X$ be the set of bounded  open intervals. With $U=(-\infty, 3)$ and $V=(0,\infty)$, we have $(f^{-1})U \cup (f^{-1}V)=X$ but $X$ is not the union of two bounded intervals. (2). Suppose $Y\in B_Y$ but $X\not \in B_X. $

Comment: thank you. I referred to 'so it is not possible that both $f^{−1}A(1)$ and $f^{−1}B(1)$ belong to $B_X$', why is that the case?  I think i don't understand the claim behind the examples, could you comment that in detail?

Comment: $\Bbb N$ is not the union of two singletons. Members of $B_X$ are singletons.